# licensing wihtout playstore and internet connection handle year check

Tags: java, android, license-key

I have to implement a licensing mechanism for an android application. Usually one could use the [licensing-service](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/) from the playstore. The catch is that the application will not be published on the playstore and the devices where the application will run, will not have access to the internet.

In my current solution i use the following parts to generate a license key:

- The android_id (Key will only work on device with that id)
- The current year (Key will only work for that year)

Here is my code

```
public void checkForLicense(){
    boolean isValid = validateKey();
    if(!isValid){
        LicenseDialog.createFrom(mContext); 
    }
}

private boolean validateKey(){
    try {
        String encoded = Settings.getInstance().getKey();
        String decoded = decode(encoded);

        if(decoded == null || decoded.equals(""))
            return false;

        boolean isSame = isSameDevice(decoded); 
        boolean isSpan = isSpanActive(decoded); 

        return isSame && isSpan;
    } catch (Exception ex){
        Log.d("DEBUG","FAILED TO VALIDATE KEY");
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean isSameDevice(String key){
    String android_id= android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    return Utils.checkIfKeyIsFromAndroidId(android_id, key);
}

private boolean isSpanActive(String key){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    return Utils.checkIfKeyIsFromCurrentYear(currentYear);
}
```

**Problem:**

The problem is right now, that one could use an expired license key by changing the date of the android device.

Are there any other options i could handle the year check?